# UITableView offset is getting changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I am reloading a table in `viewWillAppear`. If I scroll a table and then go to another screen and come back to same screen then table's scroll position gets changed. Why `UITableview` is changing scroll position, number of section, number of rows, content is same.

Comment: As you are reloading tableView in `viewWillAppear`, it will get called everytime whenever you see that screen. Instead of reloading on `viewWillAppear`, reload on `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Guys No matters reloadData change contentinset ,,, reloadData not a issue

Comment: What is the issue? Either your scrolling is change or your tableview data is changed??

Comment: Scrolling gets changed.

Comment: Do you mind adding some code so that others can actually see what's wrong with your logic?

Comment: set contentoffset in viewwillappear before reloading table

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller), whenever your UI appeared on the screen the `viewWillAppear` will called. And here you reloading the tableview so which bring to the tableview to its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

You can put reload of tableView according to your requirement.

1. If you want to reload your new data on everytime you come to that screen then you can use `viewWillAppear`.

   `func viewWillAppear()`
2. If you want to reload only once your data fetched then you can add fetch method in `viewDidLoad` and then reload.

   `func viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score -1):

You can save contentOffset of the tableView and in viewWillAppear after [tableView reloadData], you can set the contentOffset of the tableView.

Comment: This is an absolute abuse of the answer option on SO. Suggestion and further questions should be in comments not as an answer. However reloading tableView doesn't scroll it at all.